# Локальная установка nodejs electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Всем привет.
Необходимо установить локально электрон на linux машину(доступа к итернету нету).
Скачал файл electron-v17.1.0-linux-x64.zip
Не могу понять как его локально установить.
Что только не перепробывал.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Как любое node.js приложение...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Electron.js** является npm пакетом, который можно установить с помощью двух пакетных менеджеров, а имеено самого *npm* и *yarn*.

Команда для установки через *npm*:

```
npm i -D electron
```

Команда для установки через *yarn*:

```
yarn add -D electron
```

Comment: Падает в ошибку, как я понимаю пытается скачать из интернета. Которого нет)
+ npm i -D Electron
12:44:20  npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
12:44:20  npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
12:44:20  npm ERR! FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/Electron failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 104.16.25.35:443

Comment: @DenisSuslov простите, не заметил сразу ваше уточнение про интернет соединение на машине. В таком случае выход только один возможен, это установить заранее на машине с интернетом в некоторую папку electron со всеми его зависимостями (их там 1287, готовьтесь много ждать), устанавливайте фреймворк указав [дополнительные параметры `--arch` и `--platform`](https://www.electronjs.org/ru/docs/latest/tutorial/installation#%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0), той машины на которую потом будете все это переносить физически или через SFTP

Comment: Я скачал с официального сайта(https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/tag/v17.1.0)  electron-v17.1.0-linux-x64.zip. Только не понимаю как его установить....

Comment: Может есть какой то вариант установить. В интернете не могу найти информацию ...P.s. Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @DenisSuslov Скачиного вами файла вам будет не достаточно для работы, вы не сможете даже добавить его как зависимость в свой проект! Cпособ  указанный выше мной в комментарии должен вам помочь.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваши ответы. Но предложенныцй вариант не подходит. Похоже ситуация без выходная....